Discord Music bot stop playing in middle of the song
im making a music bot for discord with discord.js and discord-player all the functions and commands works but when it starts playing the song at the middle stops and throw me this error message
node:events:496
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

SocketError: other side closed
    at TLSSocket.onSocketEnd (/home/runner/MusicBotMolina/node_modules/undici/lib/client.js:1129:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:530:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Emitted 'error' event on BodyReadable instance at:
    at BodyReadable.emit (/home/runner/MusicBotMolina/node_modules/undici/lib/api/readable.js:71:18)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  code: 'UND_ERR_SOCKET',
  socket: {
    localAddress: '172.31.196.31',
    localPort: 40896,
    remoteAddress: '172.217.142.135',
    remotePort: 443,
    remoteFamily: 'IPv4',
    timeout: undefined,
    bytesWritten: 1217,
    bytesRead: 885238
  }
}

i already tried change the search engine change the delay
this is the code for the player
client.player = new Player(client, {
  ytdlOptions: {
    quality: "highestaudio",
    highWaterMark: 1 << 25,
  },
  ffmpeg_options: {
    options: "-vn -f -opus",
    before_options: "reconnect 1 reconnect_streamed 1 reconnect_delay_max 200",
  },
});

